# How do I close a Treeview and revert to my main window?

Tags: tkinter, treeview

Tkinter program. From the drop down menu I select "Show Treeview". This creates a treeview with many records from a database. After reviewing the records I want to exit the treeview and return to my main window. How do I close the treeview and return to the main window?
Code in Menu:

```
reportmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
reportmenu.add_command(label="Run a report", command=Run_Report)
reportmenu.add_command(label="Show Treeview...", command=Tree_View)
reportmenu.add_command(label="Close Treeview...",command= Close_Tree)
```

Code for Treeview:

```
def Tree_View():

    tree=ttk.Treeview(frame1,column=("column1","column2","column3","column4","column5"),show="headings")
    tree.heading("#1", text="Investment",anchor=tk.W)
    tree.heading("#2", text="Report Date",anchor=tk.W)
    tree.heading("#3", text="Value",anchor=tk.W)
    tree.heading("#4", text="Exchange Rate",anchor=tk.W)
    tree.heading("#5", text="Total Value",anchor=tk.W)
    tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

    sPrinciple=e_SelectInv.get()

    Sql=("SELECT Principle as Investment, RptDate as Report_Date, printf('%,.2f',RptVal) as Report_Value, printf('%.2f',ExchRate) as Exchange_Rate, printf('%,d',RptVal*ExchRate) as Total_Value FROM MyInv WHERE Principle = ?" +
             "order by Id Asc")

    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/TrackMyInv')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(Sql,(sPrinciple,)) 
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
            tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
    conn.close
```

Code to **close treeview and revert to main window**

```
def Close_Tree():
???????
```

Can someone please tell me what code should appear in Close_Tree to accomplish the above

Comment: Make the treeview on a separate window? And close that window.

Comment: That was a great suggestion. Works fine. Thanks